# Is react-native-encrypted-storage is not secure ,Is it possible to make it secure?

Tags: react-native

I have been using react-native-encrypted-storage in project and its been flagged by cyber security team for multiple files based on dependency com.google.crypto.tink which seems to be dependency of androidX crypto from which EncryptedSharedPreference is created, is there anything I can do regarding that or is there any other package that I can look into for better package to store persisted data?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what data you are storing, but you can store strings/tokens securely using [react-native-keychain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keychain)

The method `setGenericPassword` can be used to store key-value pairs.